# Written row has all default values (null, 0, etc.)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.1 and trying to insert a row into a remote database that connects through an SSH tunnel and it's reading just fine. I have a local DB and various remote DB's. This code used to work, I just cloned my droplet in DigitalOcean so that it would point to another remote DB and the issue arose.

I get a primary key ID back when I create the remote `Promotion` but when I read it back and check it on MySQL Workbench all the fields have default values, mostly `NULL` and `0`. Any idea what's going on?

The below config is for the remote DB I'm trying to write to.

**DB Config**

```
'prod' => [
    'read'      => [
        'options' => [
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET time_zone = \'-04:00\''
            ]
    ],
    'write'     => [],
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('PROD_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port'      => env('PROD_DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database'  => env('PROD_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username'  => env('PROD_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password'  => env('PROD_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

**Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Remote;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Promotion extends Model
{
    protected $connection = null;
    protected $table = 'Tournament';
    protected $primaryKey = 'tournamentId';
    protected $guarded = ['tournamentId'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connection = env('APP_ENV');
    }

    public function gameplayLogs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('GamePlayLog', 'tournamentId');
    }

    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('status', 3);
    }
}
```

** Creation **

```
public function deployPromotionMain($id)
{
    $post = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
    $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $promo = \Promotion::with(['assets'])->find($id);

    $data = [
        'name'                      => $promo->name,
        'description'               => $promo->description,
        'gameId'                    => intval($promo->gameId),
        'categoryId'                => intval($promo->categoryId),
        'subCategoryId'             => intval($promo->subCategoryId),
        'advertiserId'              => $promo->advertiserId,
        'advertiserCost'            => 0,
        'gamePlays'                 => $promo->gamePlays,
        'promoStartDate'            => '2015-01-01 00:00:00',
        'promoEndDate'              => '2015-01-02 00:00:00',
        'createdDate'               => $today,
        'updatedDate'               => $today,
        'promoFileDuration'         => 0,
        'eventStartDate'            => $promo->promoStartDate,
        'eventEndDate'              => $promo->promoEndDate,
        'eventStartTime'            => '0:00 AM',
        'eventEndTime'              => '11:00 PM',
        'minPlays'                  => 1,
        'maxPlays'                  => 0,
        'minAge'                    => 18,
        'maxAge'                    => 0,
        'scoringId'                 => 1,
        'minLevel'                  => 1,
        'maxLevel'                  => 0,
        'tournamentDifficultyId'    => 1,
        'timeId'                    => 1,
        'timeOut'                   => 15,
        'defaultPrice'              => 0,
        'limitGames'                => 1,
        'distributorId'             => 0,
        'stateId'                   => 0,
        'locationTypeId'            => 0,
        'questionSetId'             => 0,
        'status'                    => 3,
        'sendEmail'                 => 1,
        'kioskModelId'              => 2,
        'triviaCategoryId'          => 1,
        'duration'                  => 0
    ];

    foreach ($promo->assets as $a) {

        switch($a['assetTypeId']) {

            case 1:
                $data['eventFilePath'] = 'uploadfiles/tournament/event/'.$a['assetName'];
                $data['promoFilePath'] = 'uploadfiles/tournament/promo/'.$a['assetName'];
                break;
            case 2:
                $data['imageFilePath'] = 'uploadfiles/tournament/image/'.$a['assetName'];
                $data['thumbnailFilePath'] = 'uploadfiles/tournament/image/'.$a['assetName'];
                break;
            case 3:
                $data['iconFilePath'] = 'uploadfiles/tournament/icon/'.$a['assetName'];
                break;
            case 7:
                $data['ruleFilePath'] = 'uploadfiles/tournament/rule/'.$a['assetName'];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    foreach ($post['env'] as $env) {

        if ($env == 'dev') {

            $dev_promo = \PromotionRemote::create($data);

... //At this point I dumped $data and it had the right values but the entry had all null's and 0's and whatnot.
```

NOTE: `\Promotion::` is the promotion in the local DB, I am basically copying it over to the remote DB.

Comment: Could you paste the piece of code where you actually create and save the object? Plus the code of DefaultRemote

Comment: Thanks. "At this point I dumped $data and it had the right values" - if everything is ok at this stagee, then something is broken in later stages. Could you paste PromotionRemote as well?

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
class Promotion extends Model
{
    ...

    public function __construct($attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);        

        $this->connection = env('APP_ENV');
    }

    ...
}
```

Because I have a constructor on my class that extends Eloquent's `Model`, I need to call `Model`'s constructor as well before I do anything.

Comment: Just a heads up, it's probably not the best thing to override Laravel's model constructor. Since the eloquent `Model` class is derived from Laravel, if they updated the constructor parameters and you did a `composer update` this would break your models. I would personally override the models `boot()` method and set your dynamic connection there.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, an example would be nice. What about creating a parent class than Extends `Model` and that sets up the connection in the constructor, so I would have only 1 constructor. Then extend all the classes like `Promotion` from that new one?